# Linq OrderedQueryAble Error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

First Thing's First I have a class to manipulate some data through a linq variable:

```
public class Result
{
    public bool LongerThan10Seconds { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CompletionTime { get; set; }
}
```

Then in a Separate class I'm using this to grab info from a linq var

```
using (var data = new ProjectEntities())
{
    Result lastResult = null;
    List<Result> dataResults = new List<Result>();

    foreach(var subResult in data.Status.Select(x => x.ID).Distinct().Select(Id => data.Status.Where(x => x.ID == Id).OrderBy(x => x.Time)))
    {
        if (lastResult != null)
        {
            if (subResult.CompletionTime.Subtract(lastResult.CompletionTime).Seconds > 10)
                dataResults.Add(subResult);
        }
        lastResult = subResult;
    }
```

however I get the error:

> Linq.IOrderedQueryAble does not contain a definition for 'CompletionTime' and no Extension method 'CompletionTime' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable.

Is anyone able to provide a solution to get around this would be much appreciated been trying to figure it out for a while but seems a bit difficult in terms of a DateTime Variable.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `subResult` holds an `IOrderedQueryable` (presumably an `IOrderedQueryable<Result>`) rather than a Result.

You have this in the foreach: `var subResult in data.Status.Select(x => x.ID).Distinct().Select(Id => data.Status.Where(x => x.ID == Id).OrderBy(x => x.Time))`. Notice what's inside the Select: `Id => data.Status.Where(x => x.ID == Id).OrderBy(x => x.Time)`. That will return an `IOrderedQueryable<T>`, not a `T` (where `T` is whatever type is in the data.Status collection).

You need to either get a single value out of that `IOrderedQueryable`, using First() or some similar method, like this:
`var subResult in data.Status.Select(x => x.ID).Distinct().Select(Id => data.Status.Where(x => x.ID == Id).OrderBy(x => x.Time).First())`

... or flatten your `IEnumerable<IQueryable<T>>` to an `IEnumerable<T>`:
`var subResult in data.Status.Select(x => x.ID).Distinct().SelectMany(Id => data.Status.Where(x => x.ID == Id).OrderBy(x => x.Time))`

Edit: You may also be having an issue where C# is uncertain what type the `var subResult` is. If they're all `Result` type objects, try replacing `var subResult` with `Result subResult`.

Comment: Hi I tried to use the First() Method but I seem to still get the same error and does not recognize the completionTime method

Comment: You may need to specify that `subResult` is of type `Result`. See edit.

Comment: Hi great suggestion I just get an error now for the foreach stating cannot convert from Status to Result

Comment: @CatLikeOlive0 What does `data.Status` actually contain?

Comment: It contains the database entity object

Comment: @CatLikeOlive0 And how would you normally convert a `Status` object to a `Result` object?

Comment: It's not necessary converting the status object mainly I am trying to find times that are over 10 seconds and putting them into a list. this is why I have the completiontime method. I am only getting the error for the original forloop now after using Result subResult

Comment: @CatLikeOlive0 It seems like your `data.Status` query gives Status objects. If that's so, and you want the `CompletionTime` property of a Result object, then you need some way of getting from a `Status` object (what you're iterating through a collection of) to a `Result` object (so that you can get the completion time).

Comment: I want to use the CompletionTimeMethod on Status Objects as they have times attached to them from the database and I need to find specific time's using my CompletionTimeMethod. Quite Confused on how to gert a status object to a result object?

Comment: @CatLikeOlive0 How would you normally get the time from a Status object?

Comment: The Time is within the Status Object with it being a Entity Class and also with it being in order within SubResult

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to use SelectMany instead your second Select method call

```
data.Status.Select(x => x.ID).Distinct()
    .SelectMany(Id => data.Status.Where(x => x.ID == Id).OrderBy(x => x.Time))
```

Comment: Hi as below I have tried this solution but I still get the error seems that the CompletionTime method is not recognized

Comment: what is real type of your subResult variable?

Comment: it's just a standard linq var

Comment: var is just a syntax sugar for not specifying real variable type, but calculating its type from left part of expression. According to your answer in another thread your linq expression returns list of Status objects, but you want to get list of Result objects. So where are your Results in Status(es)? Is Status class has property with Result type?

Comment: Status is the database object where as result is a class im using to manipulate certain data