# LINQ Cannot Implicitily Convert

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, implicit-conversion

Seem to be having a problem trying to set a class to my linq variable:

Here's the class for manipulating data from the database:

```
public class Result
{
    public bool LongerThan10Seconds { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CompletionTime { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
}
```

Then I use this LINQ Statement in regards to getting data from the specific database:

```
foreach (var query in data.AssetStatusHistories
                          .Where(x => x.TimeStamp <= ft)
                          .Where(x => x.AssetID == guid))
{
    if (lastResult != null)
    {
        if ((query.TimeStamp - lastResult.CompletionTime).TotalSeconds > 10)
        {
            dataResults.Add(new Result() { Id = query.ID,
                                           longitude = query.Longitude, 
                                           latitude = query.Latitude });
        }
        lastResult = query; // <-- Error Is Here
    }
}
```

The Error being lastResult = Query, I keep getting the Cannot Implicitly Convert "Project.Data" to "Project.Result" does anyone have any recommended solutions?

I've seen a few in regards to this error but not specifically to LINQ.

Comment: Well the error is exactly what it sounds like. It seems that `lastResult` is a `Project.Data` type and your `query` is a `Project.Result`.

Comment: Did you maybe mean to set `lastResult = dataResults`?

Comment: Did you solve it or not? Your question is actually a duplicate of your earlier question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710957/linq-orderedqueryable-error

Comment: This was part of the solution but I'm pretty unsure I actually need lastResult = query;

Answer (score 4):

It tells you exactly what it means: you cannot convert `Project.Data` to `Project.Result`.

`data.AssetStatusHistories.Where(x => x.TimeStamp <= ft)
                    .Where(x => x.AssetID == guid)` does not return a collection of `Project.Result` objects, but objects of type `Project.Data`.

**EDIT**

If your lastResult is of type `Result`, I assume you could just type:

```
lastResult = new Result(){Id = query.ID,
                          longitude = query.Longitude,
                          latitude = query.Latitude });
```

But it won't work in that case. It's NOT a linq-related problem. Your `lastResult` object is assigned somewhere else. If you want to assign a new `lastResult` object at the end, where do you want to get it's `CompletionTime` property value from? In code I've pasted is not assigning it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
**lastResult = query;** <--Error Is Here
```

the variable `lastResult` will probably of type `IQueryable<Project.Result>`, but you're putting in a collection of `IQueryable<Project.Data>` from the `data.AssetStatusHistories.Where(x => x.TimeStamp <= ft) .Where(x => x.AssetID == guid)` code.

Basically it means one cannot convert a `Project.Data` to `Project.Result`.

**Try maybe giving us more context of the Project.Data class, so we can see what you're trying to achieve? And what is happening BEFORE the foreach loop. And why are you saying `lastResult=query`?**
 By providing these details we might maybe help out more!